# Some of the JavaScript code doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML select which onchange fires a function run()

```
<select id="select-para" onchange="run();">
  <option value="paragraph 1...">Para 1</option>
  <option value="paragraph 2...">Para 2</option>
  <option value="paragraph 3...">Para 3</option>
  <option value="paragraph 4....">Para 4</option>
</select>
```

What run() does is that it set value of select equals a variable text and value of text is set equal to value of input box.

```
function run(){
var text = document.getElementById("select-para").value;

var storyTextarea = document.getElementById("storytext");
storyTextarea.value = text;
}
```

I am making a typing test and I want user to select paragraph of his choice. Problem is that after this function ends, the rest of typing test code doesn't fire. Paragraph in input box changes but rest of typing test code doesn't work. How to make rest of code work? Rest of code is here.

```
var textArr = text.split(" ");
var usertext = "";
var lastWord = ""
var usertextArr = new Array();
var mistakes = new Array();
var highlightArgs = new Array();
var score = 0;
var count = 0;
var highlightIndex = 0;

//Prevent pasting into user text box
$('textarea').bind("cut paste", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}); 

//Keep highlighted text responsive
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    $(".highlightTextarea").css('width','100%');
    $(".highlightTextarea-container").css('width','99%');

    if (highlightArgs.length > 0){
        updateHighlight();
    }
});

//Jump to next word to be typed
function textJump(jumpIndex){
    var textStr = text.substring(0, jumpIndex);
    storyTextarea.value = textStr;
    storyTextarea.scrollTop = storyTextarea.scrollHeight;
    storyTextarea.value = text;
}

//Jump to specified line of TextArea
//OLD METHOD DO NOT USE
function textareaJump(line){
  storyTextarea = document.getElementById("storytext");
  var lht = (storyTextarea.clientHeight / storyTextarea.rows)*0.875;
  var jump = (line - 1) * lht;
  storyTextarea.scrollTop = jump;
}

//Refresh the highlighted area
function updateHighlight(){
    $('#storytext').highlightTextarea('destroy');
    $('#storytext').highlightTextarea({ ranges: highlightArgs });
}

function typeTest(){

  function updateUsertext(){
    usertext = $('textarea#usertext').val();
    var usertextLatestArr = usertext.split(" ");
    usertextArr.push(usertextLatestArr[usertextLatestArr.length-1]);
    count = usertextArr.length - 1;
    var wordLen = textArr[count].length;
    var charBufferIndex = textArr[count].length < 3 ? 5 : 2;

    //Word spelling matches
    if(textArr[count] === usertextArr[count]){
      if (mistakes[mistakes.length-1] === count){ mistakes.pop() }
      score++;
      highlightArgs.push({ color: '#c1f5b0', start: highlightIndex, length: wordLen })
      highlightIndex += (wordLen + 1);
    }

    //Missed one word
    //any more than a single consecutive missed word counts as an error
    else if(textArr[count+1] === usertextArr[count]){
      usertextArr.splice(count, 0, "blank");
      if (mistakes[mistakes.length-1] === count){ mistakes.pop() }
      score++;
      mistakes.push(count);
      highlightArgs.push({ color: '#febbb9', start: highlightIndex, length: wordLen })
      highlightIndex += (wordLen + 1);
      highlightArgs.push({ color: '#c1f5b0', start: highlightIndex, length: textArr[count+1].length })
      highlightIndex += (textArr[count+1].length + 1);
    }

    //Spelling mistake
    else{
      highlightArgs.push({ color: '#febbb9', start: highlightIndex, length: wordLen })
      highlightIndex += (wordLen + 1);
      mistakes.push(count);
    }

    //Rebuild the highlight object
    updateHighlight();

    //Jump to the next word
    var jumpIndex = highlightIndex + (wordLen + 1) + charBufferIndex;
    textJump(jumpIndex);
  };

  //User presses backspace
  $('#usertext').on('keydown', function(e) {
    var lastChar = $('textarea#usertext').val().slice(-1);
    var secondLastChar = $('textarea#usertext').val().slice(-2).substring(0, 1);;
    if(e.keyCode == 8 && lastChar === " " && secondLastChar !== " "){
      usertextArr.pop();
      mistakes.pop();
      highlightArgs.pop();
      updateHighlight();
      highlightIndex -=  ( textArr[count].length + 1 );
      count--;
    }
  });

  $('#usertext').on('keydown', function(e) {
    var lastChar = $('textarea#usertext').val().slice(-1);
    var spaceTest = lastChar === " " ? true : false;
    if(e.keyCode == 32 && spaceTest == false){
      updateUsertext();
    }
  }); 
}
```

How to make all code work and typing test function smoothly. Here is the HTML:

```
<select id="select-para" onchange="run();">
      <option value="paragraph 1...">Para 1</option>
      <option value="paragraph 2...">Para 2</option>
      <option value="paragraph 3...">Para 3</option>
      <option value="paragraph 4....">Para 4</option>
    </select>
<div class="typebox">
            <textarea id="storytext" name="storytext" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="typebox">
            <textarea id="usertext" name="usertext" type="text" class="form-control" rows="2" placeholder="Start typing here to begin the test..."></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="timer">You have <span id="time" class="timerTime">02:00</span> minutes left.</div>
```

Comment: Where is your typeTest() method being called from? You state that method is working after the run() method is called but is occurring? Are you getting error in your console?

Comment: This is a "fix it all for me pls", and as such is too broad. Are you able to narrow it down?

Answer (score 0):

Add typeTest() while onChange of paragraph

```
<select id="select-para" onchange="run(); typeTest();">
```

include the

```
 $("#usertext").bind("cut paste", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 });

 //Keep highlighted text responsive
 $(window).on('resize', function(){
    $(".highlightTextarea").css('width','100%');
    $(".highlightTextarea-container").css('width','99%');

    if (highlightArgs.length > 0){
       updateHighlight();
   }
});
```

in run() function, so that the handlers get registered.

remove "textarea" from, as it is not needed to identify the ID.

```
$("textarea#usertext")
```

The logic may need to be properly formatted to work properly for all the other keycodes apart from '8' bs and '32' space.

Comment: Sir, the code works fine if I provide a paragraph in  javascript but after adding drop-down, the paragraph changes in text-box but timer doesn't start. Creating another function typetest() to fire rest of code doesn't make it work either. Please help me, I am stuck from two days.

Comment: Timer was not starting for me from your code. Need to start it every time you change the paragraph I guess. You are defining typeTest() function, then it will not be triggered unless you call it from HTML. So remove typeTest() function, so that the jQuery calls get registered automatically from script.